# Setter dependency injection or locator pattern

Tags: design, design-patterns, php

Let's say that I have the following class.

```
class Application 
{
     protected $dependency;
     public function setDependency($type)
     {
          $this->dependency = ServiceLocator->getServiceFor($type);
     }
     
     public function execute()
     {
          $this->dependency->handle();
     }
}
```

The **$type** variable can be accessed globally. Essentially is a query parameter which can be accessed from the URL.

```
$type = $_GET['type'];
```

Does it make sense in this case to have a setter method and pass a variable ( which can be accessed globally ) and then pass it to the ServiceLocator in order to get the dependency that the class needs ?

Or it is better to just ask for the dependency and let the ServiceLocator handle the global variable

```
class Application 
{
     
     public function execute()
     {
          ServiceLocator.getService()->handle();
     }
}
```

```
class ServiceLocator 
{
    protected $type;
    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->type = $_GET['type'];
    }
    public function getService()
    {
         if ($this->type == 'A')
         {
             return new ServiceA();
         }
         elseif ( $this->type == 'B')
         {
             return new ServiceB();
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Neither of these examples is [Dependency Injection](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). It’s the [Service Locator Pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) in both cases.

If it was [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) the code receiving injections wouldn’t know that any “service locator” exists. Code that maps the type to the string would be at the top of the call stack, usually main. Because that’s where construction would be happening.

Instead you’ve got a service locator that isn’t sure what its responsibilities are.

I can tell you if your service locator services other services besides this service it’s going to be a busy place if it keeps getting involved in service details like this.

Since you’re committed to using the service locator let me explain my concern about service details.

Service locator should take on constructing services. It should not take on business logic. It shouldn’t be making behavioral decisions. If you think it must then first try redesigning services so that they don’t need the results of logic. Design them ready to perform that logic.

Keep construction as simple as possible. Move logic into methods.

Comment: your suggestion is to create the service outside the Application class?  .Furthermore, I didn’t understand what you mean when you said that I’ve got a locator that doesn’t know that it’s responsibilities are, could you please explain ? How is the service locator supposed to know how to create a service without looking up the possible services that can be created ?

Comment: Service locator and dependency injection are two different competing patterns.  I can help you with either one. But not both at the same time. Which would you like help with?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I will need help with the locator pattern, that’s where you lost me. I didn’t understand your explanation

Comment: @OrestisuRic better now?

Comment: But if you don’t have the logic you don’t know which service to construct right ? Therefore, the service locator just returns the service that is created in another class which is responsible for creating the service. Correct me if I’m wrong

Comment: @OrestisuRic it’s better to put such logic in factory methods rather than service locators or constructors.